# If $f$ is an integrable function on the interval $[0, 1]$ with given conditions, prove that $\int^1_0 f > 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Say that $f$ is an integrable function on the interval $[0, 1]$ such that

(a) for all $x\in[0, 1], f(x) \geq 0$, and

(b) there is some $c \in[0, 1]$ at which $f$ is continuous, and $f(c) > 0$.

I'm trying to prove that $\int^1_0 f > 0$.

Based on the given information in (a): I can see that values $f(x)$ must exist at all values on this interval, if for all $x \in [0,1]$, there is a value $f(x) \geq 0$.

You can see that $f(x)$ for a random point $x$ isn't negative, so its integrals will also not be negative. This is generally true on the interval also.

From (b), we see that there will be a point of continuity where $f(c)$ is not negative. I know an integrable function is not necessarily continuous, we have a step toward uniform continuity on $[0,1]$ -> Unless we just can say $c$ is any point on the interval, so they're all continuous.

The formal proof of this is definitely still eluding me, because I can't figure out why (b) is useful for proving continuity on the interval.

Comment: If $f(c)=a>0$, then by continuity you have an interval around $c$ where $f(x)>a/2$. Now restrict to that interval.

Comment: So a continuous function can be integrated, and you know that the integral value would be positive in this restricted interval?

Comment: You already know $f$ can be integrated and you do not need to prove it is continuous. And yes the overall integral is $\geq$ to the integral on just this subinterval.

Comment: Also understand that you do not know that "$f$ is a continuous function". That phrase means $f$ is continuous at *every point* of $[0,1]$. You only know that $f$ is continuous at a single point $c$. It may or may not be continuous at the other points of $[0,1]$. So if you had not been told specifically that $f$ was integrable, there would be no way to show it.